# NodeJs, get b64 from chunk of remote .jpeg

Tags: node.js, base64, fs

I am working with an  API who go search pictures in a DMS and allow us to download it. I looks like this:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);

var httpsRequest = https.request({
  method: 'GET',
  ...
  }, function (response) {

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      file.write(chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      file.end();  
      res.download(...);
    });
});
```

I now need to display the image and not "just" download it. For example for an jpeg image, I tried to encode in b64 the buffer :

> console.log(file._writableState.bufferedRequest.chunk.toString());

to then use it simply in web page. But I get something like this :

from :

> chunk: *<*Buffer a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02
>   8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0 02 8a 28 a0
>   04 a2 96 8a 00 6e 29 08 a7 ... >

to

> 8Vupis7dLZUHzyrhnH1qKMxsoMasjMPl3DJPqeelKRAhVlhVShysS5Jz/eI9aQxcMz7z5hbqpkbp7n0pzZk ... TA08GoRUgNS0BIDTxUYp4qWNDqWg==

But when I try to get back the picture with some online b64 decode it doesn t work.

If someone already had to work this it and had a solution.

PS full code :

```
collection.findOne({}, function(document){

var fileUrl = url.parse(encodeURI(document.toObject().__metadata.media_src));
var fileName = fileUrl.pathname;

var mimetype = mime.lookup(fileName);
res.setHeader('Accept',mimetype);
res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);

var httpsRequest = https.request({
    method: 'GET',
    host: fileUrl.hostname,
    path: fileUrl.pathname,
    headers: sharepoint.headers(mimetype, fileName)
}, function (response) {

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        file.write(chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
        file.end();
     console.log(file._writableState.bufferedRequest.chunk.toString('base64'));
        setTimeout(function () {

            res.download(fileName, decodeURI(fileName), function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(err.status).end();
                }

                 fs.unlink(fileName);
             });
         }, 300);
     });
 });

 httpsRequest.end();
 });
```

Comment: Post your full code please, I believe I know your error, but can't be sure, since there is no base64 encoding being done in your code. And why do you need base64, maybe you can just display the image as `image/jpg` the answer will be much simpler.

Comment: tried to add 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +base64, no result

Comment: Not sure I can go from buffer to image/jpg like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing when trying to convert to base64, is that you're using streams wrong.

```
console.log(file._writableState.bufferedRequest.chunk.toString());
```

`file._writableState.bufferedRequest` only contains the current buffer, if the buffer has been flushed, which most likely is the case, you will get a partial base64 of the whole image, that's why you can't display it. The buffer is flushed every 16kb by default for `fs.createWritableStream`, that value comes from `highWaterMark` option. (Don't change that value)

You should **not** access those "private" properties of the stream, unless you really know what you're doing.

Instead if you only want to return the image as base64, use:

```
response.setEncoding('base64');
```

And pipe it to express response object.

```
const httpsRequest = https.request({
    method: 'GET',
    host: fileUrl.hostname,
    path: fileUrl.pathname,
    headers: sharepoint.headers(mimetype, fileName)
}, response => {
    response.setEncoding('base64');
    response.pipe(res);
});

httpsRequest.end();
```

There is no need to save it to a temporary file.

Now you can display it using:

```
<!-- Get the image via AJAX, and add `src` -->
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{base64-from-api}" />
```

---

If you want to display the image directly, as `image/jpeg` instead of `base64`, remove `response.setEncoding('base64')` and just leave `response.pipe` then you will be able to:

```
<img src="/path/to/image/route" />
```

Comment: Thx for your answer and the explanation but the response object return all information on the request. It's like huge and I didn't seefield that looked like buffer / b64 string.

Comment: What? My answer works, I don't understand what you're saying. `but response object return all information on the request`, what are you trying to achieve, or what isn't working?

Comment: I may misunderstood pipe functionnality. If I take your solution and I `console.log(response.pipe(res)); ` I get something like : 
ServerResponse {
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { finish: [ [Function: resOnFinish], [Function: onevent], [Object] ] ....

Comment: But why are you trying to `console.log` on a `stream` you don't need to! Don't test on the console, test that the http response is correct,which it is, it is the image base64 encoded. use `curl` or just use the browser `GET`

Comment: I know I know It was stupid but I was desesperated. I thought It didn t work cause it launched a download on my computer but I didn t see the b64 string was into it. Not sure if this the expected result but I can work from there.Thx again

Comment: It's sending a download, because maybe you set force download headers, remove those headers, and you will see a b64 string directly. `res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);` remove that header, if you don't wish a download.